# Load javascript as preload

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have application in React and I use React from CDN.

When I set standard script with CDN all works.

I'd like force on browser to get scripts earlier.

```
<link rel="preload" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react.min.js" as="script" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="preload" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react-dom.min.js" as="script" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

but when I use this manner than is error that React doesn't exists.

Does exists any way to force on browser to get libraries as soon as possible and provide for my library?

Because this libraries are download (I see in inspector) but react app can't detect it. It looks like browser doesn't treat this files as scripts.

Comment: How your app script is loaded ?

Comment: I've been tried before </body> as script and as prefetch in head but then it isn't load. And also I've tried as preload but then is error because app is on localhost and is load earlier than CDN